# Javascript check if any elements in array are equal

Tags: javascript

How should I make a function that loops through an array, and checks if any elements are equal

Example:

```
[a, b, c, d] //false
[a, b, a, d] //true
```

EDIT:

I want to use it with nested arrays, like so:

```
const a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] //false
const b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,1]] //true
```

EDIT again:
I want the nested arrays to be the exact same

```
const a = [[1,2],[4,5]] //false
const b = [[1,2],[1,2]] //true
const c = [[1,2][3,4][1,2]] //true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as:

```
const getResult = (arr) => new Set(arr).size !== arr.length;
```

You can add all elements to set and then compare `size` of `set` and `length` of `arr`.

> You will get different length if any element is repeated else same

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; //false
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd']; //true

const getResult = (arr) => new Set(arr).size !== arr.length;
console.log(getResult(arr1));
console.log(getResult(arr2));
```

If you want to use nested array then you can flat it before seinding `arguments` to `getResult` function as:

```js
const a = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
]; //false
const b = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 1],
]; //true

const getResult = (arr) => new Set(arr).size !== arr.length;
console.log(getResult(a.flat()));
console.log(getResult(b.flat()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to loop through the array and check if the first index of the element is same as current index like this:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b = [1, 2, 3, 1]
    let isRepeated = (a) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.indexOf(a[i]) !== i)
          return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    console.log(isRepeated(a));
    console.log(isRepeated(b));
```